# How do machine-check exception (MCE) work?

Tags: linux, hardware, x86, cpu-architecture, mcelog

I want to understand how CPU performs this Machine checks and how does it detect if any device has failed?

Does the device send any [machine-check exception (MCE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception) event which the MCE daemon catches and reports?

How does this works internally?